# Django always returns error 404 with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

I have a problem with Django. Application's url config looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^api/', include(api_urls.getUrls())),
    url(r'^api/vk.com/buy.coins/$', VkPaymentsView.as_view()),
    url(r'^api/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-testing/((?P<method_code>[\w\./-]+?)/)?$', TestingView.as_view()),
)
```

I try to request right url:

```
http://example.com/api-testing/
```

but I have a 404 error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://example.com/api-testing//
```

I see an extra trailing slash, can it be cause of problem?

Application launches in FastCGI mode with nginx:

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=localhost port=9001 pidfile=$RUNFILES_PATH/$SITE.pid
```

This is the fastcgi params in nginx:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$domain/$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;

fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri;
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
fastcgi_intercept_errors off;

fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;

fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

fastcgi_param REDIRECT_STATUS 200;
```

Comment: The two slashes in your will definitely cause a problem.

Comment: @arulmr, I think so too. But how this appeared? Even in nginx debug log url has one trailing slash.

Comment: check your [`APPEND_SLASH`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) setting in the `settings.py` file.

Comment: @arulmr, it doesn't resolves the problem, symptoms the same. But there is the new observation: if I try url without slash (`http://example.com/api-testing`), I have error 404 too. But now error text such this: `Request URL: http://example.com/api-testing/` (one trailing slash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Problem was in FastCGI param `SCRIPT_NAME`. And I added in Django location directive `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME ''`. And the problem has disappeared.

```
location @django {
    fastcgi_pass localhost:9001;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME '';
}
```